# Filemaker PSoS go to layout

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to use Perform Script on Server function to improve speed of my database.

I make a very simple function but the "go to layout" function doesn't works. I used a field to make sure that the function is running on server.

"Main script":

> perform script on server [Wait for completion; "PSOS script"]

"PSOS script":

> set Field [Table::field ; Table::field & " PSOS script is running on server "]
>   go to layout["simpleLayout"]

"OnFirstWindowOpen"

> If[LeftWords (Get (ApplicationVersion) ; 1) = "Server")]
>   `set Field [Table::field ; Table::field & " OnFirstWindowOpen is running on server "]`
>   `Exit Script[];`
>   End If

When I run the "Main script" the result of Table::field is:" OnFirstWindowOpen is running on server PSOS script is running on server", but I stay in the same layout.

My database is host in FMPhost.com cloud filemaker server 14.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is confusing you is that when you perform a script on server, the server actually opens a separate instance of the database on the server.

It runs the startup script first, then your specified script.
You will not see any layout navigation in your local FileMaker as the layout change happens in the instance the server has opened.

You need to do all navigation scripting directly, for example by moving your go to layout step to your main script after the perform on server step.

More info on the function [here.](http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref1.36.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to layout is PSOS compatible

Unless your PSOS script sets the global field, this field has to be on the first layout open.

Try to add another go to layout script step before you set the field through PSOS.

Another option - set the error capture on and parse the error back to your local script or check server log to track the issue.

> go to layout["simpleLayout"]

Are you trying to pass a layout name into calculation? You need to either select it from the list or use layout number

Comment: I have tried everything: Only "go to layout" function, layouts from the list, with layout number. The layout doesn't have any "onLayoutEnter" script trigger...

Comment: It doesn't return me any error and I can't see the server error log. The hosting provider doesn't include that feature.

Comment: how do you specify layout for "go to layout"? Did you try to add another go to layout before specifying the field? It will not return your error unless you add error trapping and pass it as a result of your PSOS

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "Go To Layout" Script step at the very beginning of the script, before "Set Field" navigating to the **layout, where you need to set that field**.

```
"PSOS script":
Go To Layout ["layoutName"]
set Field [Table::field ; Table::field & " PSOS script is running on server "]
go to layout["simpleLayout"]
```

Comment: I set the field only to know if the script was running. I already try to run the script only with the go to layout function

Comment: Let me clarify the issue: are you concerned that the field is not set, or you are concerned that you remain on the same layout and not being navigated to the "simpleLayout"?